# How to call jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this jquery function :

```
$("#settingsNavTabsIntegrationContent").on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    ...
});
```

and then i want to call the function above on my new function as below :

```
$("#settingsNavTabsIntegrationContent").on('click', '.sourceFieldRecordUL', function () {
   // call the function above
});
```

the first function is used when i 'click' the box/text in the choice in dropdown of checkbox options.

the second function is for when i click on the area around the text/checkbox.

how is the correct way to call it? or any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: Use : `$("#settingsNavTabsIntegrationContent input[type="checkbox"]").trigger("change")`

Comment: Assign function in a variable and use anywhere you want

Comment: @Swati thanks for your advice, i will try using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in both the call, but technically we should use the change for the checkbox. Whenever you will change an event you will get the real value of that input using event object

```
$("#settingsNavTabsIntegrationContent").on('change', '.sourceFieldRecordUL', function (e) 
{
   // call the function above
});
```

However, in the above function, you might face an issue if your content is loading after registration of event or dynamic content

**Suggested approach is**

```
$(document).on('change', '#settingsNavTabsIntegrationContent', function () 
{
   // call the function above
})
```

This function will not fail if your content is loading dynamically or after the script load.

Comment: Hi, the goal is that i want to add a function when i CLICK on the AREA around TEXT/CHECKBOX, so it may appear as the same -or so- function as CLICK at /CHANGEd value of TEXT/CHECKBOX.

Answer (score 1):

Assign function in a variable and use anywhere you want. Try the below code for example:

```
const myFunc = function () {
   ...
}

$("#settingsNavTabsIntegrationContent").on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', myFunc);

$("#settingsNavTabsIntegrationContent").on('click', '.sourceFieldRecordUL', function () {
   // call the function above
   myFunc();
});
```

Checkout this blog for reference: https://dmitripavlutin.com/6-ways-to-declare-javascript-functions

Comment: Alternative syntax is:  `function myFunc() { ... }`  then call it the same way `myFunc()` or directly as event handler as in the examples above

Comment: Yes that's also correct. I'm more of a typescript user so I'm more into arrow functions that's why this syntax.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan thanks for your advice, i will try using it.

Comment: @iqbal does this answer your question?

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan yes, more or less. got the idea of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you really want to know, but let me try to give you a possible answers:-

1. If your question is related to registering an event then the best way to use Jquery '**trigger**' method to attach events.
2. If you question attaching multiple events on the same id, then I would suggest you **separate your IDs** and events else it could give you a **bubble-up** events issue.